# MongoDb Query Array on C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Im dba and development a C# Web App to get information from Mongodb, but when i try to get information from an array attribute, the C# show me all element of the document that contain the element that i find. I just want to get the specific element, not all.

I have this document: 

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b1b7dcb830980744687bd4"),
    "i_nombre" : "Centro Comercial",
    "i_direccion" : {
        "i_d_pais" : "Panamá",
        "i_d_ciudad" : "Panamá",
        "i_d_provincia" : "Panamá",
        "i_d_distrito" : "Chilibre",
        "i_d_corregimiento" : "Alcalde Diaz",
        "i_d_calle" : "Primera"
    },
    "i_correo_e" : "imqv@imqv.com.pa",
    "i_telefono" : {
        "i_t_iglesia" : "268-5000",
        "i_t_colegio" : "268-5001",
        "i_t_radio" : "268-5002"
    },
    "i_estado" : 1,
    "i_sector" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b6d903b8309826e891eefe"),
            "i_s_color" : "Amarillo",
            "i_s_localizacion" : {
                "i_s_l_provincia" : "Panamá",
                "i_s_l_distrito" : "Chilibre",
                "i_s_l_corregimiento" : "San Miguelito"
            },
            "i_s_supervisor" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b6d903b8309826e89100f0"),
            "i_s_color" : "Rojo",
            "i_s_localizacion" : {
                "i_s_l_provincia" : "Panamá",
                "i_s_l_distrito" : "Arraijan",
                "i_s_l_corregimiento" : "Burunga"
            },
            "i_s_supervisor" : []
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b6d903b8309826e89220f0"),
            "i_s_color" : "Azul",
            "i_s_localizacion" : {
                "i_s_l_provincia" : "Panamá",
                "i_s_l_distrito" : "Colon",
                "i_s_l_corregimiento" : "Chilibre"
            },
            "i_s_supervisor" : []
        }
    ]
}`;

When i execute this query on mongodb

`db.iglesia.find
(
      { "_id" : ObjectId("53b1b7dcb830980744687bd4") } 
    , { 
        i_sector: { 
                    $elemMatch: {  "_id" : ObjectId("53b6d903b8309826e891eefe") }
                  }
      }
);`

i get:

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b1b7dcb830980744687bd4"),
    "i_sector" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53b6d903b8309826e891eefe"),
            "i_s_color" : "Amarillo",
            "i_s_localizacion" : {
                "i_s_l_provincia" : "Panamá",
                "i_s_l_distrito" : "Chilibre",
                "i_s_l_corregimiento" : "San Miguelito"
            },
            "i_s_supervisor" : []
        }
    ]
}`

Question: How i can get the same result with C#? Just with the $elemMatch that i set on Query.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: I wrotte this C# query `Console.Write( ( gaq_act.gaq_nnc("GaQ")).GetCollection("iglesia") .Find( Query.ElemMatch("i_sector", Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse("53b6d903b8309826e89100f0"))) ) );`, but the query show the 3 element of the i_sector array, and the mongo query just show one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your Mongo shell query is not a find with 2 filters, by church id and sector, it is actually a find by church id and a projection by sector id. You have arranged the braces funny, that's all.

This has 2 filters and no projection:

```
db.iglesia.find ({"_id": "53b1b7dcb830980744687bd4", i_sector: { $elemMatch: {"_id" : "53b6d903b8309826e891eefe"}}}).pretty()
```

This has a filter and projection:

```
db.iglesia.find ({"_id": "53b1b7dcb830980744687bd4"}, {i_sector: { $elemMatch: { "_id": "53b6d903b8309826e891eefe"}}}).pretty()
```

A complete C# example, for these 2 cases using a newer driver, version 2.3, [here on rextester](http://rextester.com/CUS12430).